# get last 30 days except weekends

Tags: sql, firebird

I am working on a SQL that brings the data from the last 30 days, however I am trying to figure out how to filter weekends. The SQL WHERE section I have now:

```
DATES >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, current_timestamp) AND DATES < 'TODAY'
```

Is there a simple solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

With [`EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATES)`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract) you get the day of the week (0=Sunday, 1=Monday, … 6=Saturday)  so you could do something like

```
   DATES >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, current_timestamp) 
AND DATES < 'TODAY' AND EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATES) >0 AND EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATES) <6
```

Comment: You could also  use `EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM DATES) between 1 and 5`

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you Luc.